# When does a browser initialize flash?

Tags: javascript, html, css, flash, pagespeed

I am working on optimizing a page that has Flash on it. I am using optimization practices like moving Javascript to the bottom to not block. Removing inline scripts. And minimizing HTTP requests with minified css and js.

The majority of the pages content is in the flash, so loading it as soon as possible is the goal. Currently there is a 2 ~ 3 second delay before the flash is even rendered (using firebug profiling)

I am wondering at what point in the page load does the browser start initializing flash on the page?

Is it once the DOM element containing the flash has been rendered?

Is it once the complete onload event has been fired?

I imagine it probably differs with each browsers as well.

Comment: To clarify. I am interested in when the flash instance will start playing/loading. I am aware that the flash instance will have its own assets to load asynchronously and most likely will still be loading when the window.onload is fired. Specifically I am interested in triggering this initialization phase of the flash instance as soon as possible.

Also I am aware that using a JS library to embed the flash will prolong the flash execution at least until the JS library is loaded and executed.

Answer (score 1):

Use a direct embed in the HTML. Don't use swfObject or the JS that the Flash IDE provides. If you use JS, you have to wait for that file to load - and then chances are, the JS is attaching to the window.onload and not rendering the SWF until then.

Comment: Flash CS5 at least actually uses swfobject :). swfobject recommends where possible (and provides a tool for) "dumb" embedding. I slightly prefer the less redundant javascript method myself, but it does load slightly slower - though I believe the main delay is the .swf download + decompress + verify which you can't really shorten :(.

Comment: Ok in the case that I don't use a JS library to embed it and use a direct embed tag. When does the flash begin loading/playing in that case? Once the browser has rendered the embed tag?

Comment: Hi all, the browser is going to need to read the HTML as it's doing so it's building the DOM, when it gets to an Embed or Object tag it's gotta get the plugin for interpreting into memory then after that it needs to start fetching the swf, the way swf files load the first frame is preloader second frame is the application code, and the frames are sent separately, the playing of said preloader should start the moment that first frame is loaded. http://www.leavethatthingalone.com/blog/index.cfm/2009/11/11/Flex4CustomPreloader

Comment: @shaunhusain if you want to submit that as an answer I will accept.

Answer (score 0):

First, none of the major browsers wait for flash before displaying the page. This means that when the HTML page finishes loading, the Flash content may not be completely loaded yet.

I assume based on these facts that the SWF loads simultaneously with the HTML. Once the HTML is loaded then the SWF is displayed.

To test you could use https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/3371/

To improve flash loading try SWF Object:

http://code.google.com/p/swfobject/

Answer (score 0):

Because Flash is treated the same way as CSS and HTML by all browsers, a browser initializes it when loading HTML (they're both loaded at the same time). The browser does not prioritise Flash above anything else.